# Kid's book about a robot called RUOK

Tags: story-identification, illustrated-story

I have a memory of reading a children's book when I was younger - around 1995? It was about a child who went on an adventure with two robots, one of which was called RUOK ("are you OK"). It was illustrated. I can't remember the title or the author. Searching for the robot's name yielded nothing relevant.

Edit: some more detail about the book itself - the pictures were in colour, the book was approximately A4 sized, soft bound, and approximately 40 pages long

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You may want to take the [tour], to understand better how our site works. You may also want to look at the answers to [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/) for suggestions on additional information you might be able to provide - it may suggest something you wouldn't have thought of listing, or prompt a memory of something more you can edit into the question.

Answer (score 3):

### [Tales of The Astro Force](https://books.google.com/books?id=2inJmC-ZnH0C&pg=PA12&dq=RUOK+robot&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCwqCVksTbAhUDvlkKHcx8AKIQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=RUOK%20robot&f=false), by J. C. Egan (2007)

Tagline: "Take a fantastic journey to the outer reaches of the unknown as the crew of the intrepid Astro Force One embarks on their most perilous mission; to rescue the beautiful Jackie Albright from the Fiendish Fish Folk of Planet Thenh."

> There she placed her eye near the retina scan, which declared for certain that she was, after all, Jackie Albright, agent Zed for the Astro Force. She then could traipse into the second inner office, where she met a robot.
>
> "Good morning Ms. Albright," said the almost human like machine, all blue and red and sparkly.
>
> "Good morning, R.U.O.K. Let me in, please. The Boss wishes to see me."

Jackie *might* be a child:

> "And Zed," he started, but she kept walking. "Jackie," he whispered. She turned around.
>
> "Yes?"
>
> "This government depends on you. The galaxy is in your hands now."
>
> She thought for a minute, and then frowned at how frustrating this all had become.
>
> "Thanks, Dad. I understand."

However, this Google Books link does not appear to be illustrated.

Comment: (This was the first Google Books search result for the query "RUOK robot".)

Comment: Well found, but unfortunately not the right book. The publication date is also off - the book I read was in existence in the mid 1990s